# How do I avoid ambiguous relationships in power bi?

Tags: merge, relationship, powerbi-desktop, edit, dashboard

I am trying to correlate more than 2 tables with each other, as there is one master table, from which I want to take date for the whole dashboard which will be the date slicer and need to connect other needed table to that master table.

I have tried **merge query** and **manage relationship** already, which correlating the table in limited way, so I want the solution which will help me to connect every single table to another one.